# colrm: command not found

Tags: linux, cygwin

I am using cygwin on the windows, tried installing the "colrm" but it does not work.

```
$ apt-get install bsdmainutils

Package bsdmainutils not found, exiting...

bash: colrm: command not found
```

Let me know what has to be followed in case of windows pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use cygcheck to inquiry the Cygwin server and ask for any package containing a specific item:

```
$ cygcheck -p usr/bin/colrm
Found 6 matches for usr/bin/colrm
...
util-linux-2.33.1-2 - util-linux: Collection of basic system utilities
```

You need to install the `util-linux` package